# Is there any law or guidelines on toll avoidance for taxi drivers in Bangkok?

Tags: thailand, taxis, fares, bangkok, tolls

When driving between two locations, the fastest and/or shortest path may have a toll, while a slower and/or longer path may be toll-free. Tolls may represent a significant part of a taxi fare (e.g., 30%).

Is there any law or guidelines on toll avoidance for taxi drivers in Bangkok? E.g. take toll-free path if it doesn't add more than 10% of travel time?

Example of two paths, one toll-free and one with toll:

[image]

Example of taxi fare where toll represents 36% of the fare (toll = 115 THB; total fare = 204 + 3 + 115 = 322 THB):

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about taxi meters or app-based drivers? And are you asking about drivers asking the passenger or just going on the toll road without consulting first? In my experience, tolls aren't included in the fare so it makes no sense for drivers to take the toll road just because it's faster.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica good point, the question indeed is more salient for the case of taxi rides whose price was determined before the ride started (e.g. some rides ordered via Internet). I'm guessing the question also applies for old-fashioned taxis as they might prefer a faster path if the main factor of the ride fare is the distance (toll path might be less crowded).

Comment: My experience—which some Internet searching says is not especially unusual—is that Bangkok taxi drivers will do their best to ask the passenger if they want to use (and pay for) the tolled roads or not. Of course, in the case of extreme language difficulties, or some kind of dishonest driver, it's possible that this will not happen 100% of the time. I was unable to find any source saying if this is the law, as your question asks, or just usual practice, so I'm leaving it as a comment for now.